# Could not upload .htaccess

Tags: svn, .htaccess, deployment, webserver, springloops

I am using Springloops to automatically take my SVN repo and deploy onto my server. I am getting the following error:

```
Could not upload .htaccess
Could not upload .htaccess using BINARY transfer
----------------------------------------------------
Connecting to dev.convrrt.com
Logging in as convrrt
Entering destination directory ~/
Entering passive mode
REVISION: 1 -> 30
Getting changes
Deleting files
Removing directories
Creating directories and files
Extracting file: .htaccess...OK
Uploading file: .htaccess [644]
R: 
interrupted
```

How can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do is to svn-ignore .htaccess. Problem solved.